# How can i re-render parent onClick in a child component [ using react-hooks ]?

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks, react-state

I want the parent app to re-fetch when a user clicks delete in the child component. My idea was to create a dummy counter state that changes on delete. however the parent state is not changing. What is the best way to do this?

Parent.js

```
function Parent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);
  const token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${BACK_PORT}/data/mypet`, { headers: { "auth-token": token } })
      .then(function (response) {
        setMyPetData(response?.data);
        // console.log("uuu", myPetData);
        console.log("ooo", response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [token, state]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Child state={state} setState={setState} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child.js

```
function Child() {
    const onDelete = ({ state, setState }) => {
      setState(state + 1)
    };
    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If `useEffect` dependencies are changed, it would run again. So you on the right track. If you could provide more code about `Child` component and how it calls `onDelete` or a codesandbox it would be great. By the way, you do not need to pass state, or at least call the `setState` that way.In fact this might be because of closures. you can call `setState` with a callback: `setState(state => (state + 1))`.

Comment: I have added it to code SandBox tho it doesn't run becasue of permissions etc.. I added your callback setState(state => (state + 1)) and I see that the state in fact updates, however the page does not change...https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-johnson-hzcxm?file=/src/components/MyPets.jsx

Comment: Does this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-wave-mz9nk?file=/src/App.js) help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the `state`, `setState` in `Child` as props, not as `onDelete`'s args:

```
function Child(props) {
    const onDelete = () => {
      props.setState(props.state + 1)
    };
    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could use a separate "triggerFetch" state to trigger another fetch. Pass a callback to the child to trigger a data fetch.

```
function Parent() {
  ...
  const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState(false); // (0) <-- create fetchData state

  const token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData && axios // (3) <-- if fetchData true, then fetch
      .get(`${BACK_PORT}/data/mypet`, { headers: { "auth-token": token } })
      .then(function (response) {
        setMyPetData(response?.data);
        // console.log("uuu", myPetData);
        console.log("ooo", response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => setFetchData(false)); // (4) <-- reset back to false when complete
  }, [fetchData, token, state]); // (2) <-- add dependency

  const triggerFetch = () => setFetchData(true); // (1) <-- set true to trigger

  return (
    <div>
      <Child fetchData={triggerFetch} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child

```
function Child({ fetchData }) {
  return (
    <div onClick={fetchData}>Click me to make parent fetch data!</div>
  )
}
```